# Accordion stoped working after i pasted it in my

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i have site running on wordpress template.
i've pasted in the whole accordion code from W3School (here it is https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp).
my version unexpectedly doesn't work.

i've included css lines in the main.css file:

```
....    
/* styles for accordion*/
    .accordion {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
/*end styles for accordion*/
```

i've added the html code on the page through the admin console:

```
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>  
    <div class="panel">   <p>Lorem ipsum</p> </div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button> 
    <div class="panel">   <p>Lorem ipsum</p> </div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button> 
    <div class="panel">   <p>Lorem ipsum</p> </div>
```

next i've created scripts.js file and added it into the template with `wp_enqueue_script` in functions.php. so i can see it loads when the page code is shown.

content of the scripts.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
          panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          panel.style.display = "block";
        }
      });
    }
});
```

then nothing happens on click on the accordion: no js errors in the console, no content of the accordion shows up. how could i make it work?

upd 1
changed class names to unique ones
js

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("nikaccordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("nikactive");
        var nikpanel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (nikpanel.style.display === "block") {
          nikpanel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          nikpanel.style.display = "block";
        }
      });
    }
```

css:

```
/* styles for accordion*/
.nikaccordion {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.nikactive, .nikaccordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.nikpanel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*end styles for accordion*/
```

html:

```
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<button class="nikaccordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="nikpanel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<button class="nikaccordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="nikpanel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
<button class="nikaccordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="nikpanel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
```

upd 2
when im changing the order of the .js files that my file goes at the end of a list then i get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js?ver=5.2.2:8)
```

so i suppose the

```
var nikpanel = this.nextElementSibling;
```

doesn't work

Comment: Not to ask a stupid question but are you including a JavaScript library in your code? If you're not then the JS script from W3 has no point of reference and won't do anything.

Comment: Here is a fiddle link that has a JS library running. The code is all the stock W3 example: https://jsfiddle.net/rcq5kb7n/

Comment: As @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 asks, do you use the script tag to include the js file? If not: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: @MartinM, i have this line in the page code 
<script type='text/javascript' src='***/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=5.1.1'></script>

Comment: In your javascript remove the first line  i.e $(document).ready(function() {  and the last line i.e }); and tell us what happens

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000, i have this line 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://***wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp'></script>
is it the library you are talking about?

Comment: @hans-könig, nothing happend

Comment: could it be that scripts.js is included higher than main.js?

Comment: Have you tested the solution I just posted?

Comment: @hans-könig i've tested it. nothing changes for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that WordPress adds p-tags to my html code thus the js script treated the phantom p-tags as target tags and tried to apply actions to them.
i disabled this addings by:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

in my functions.php

Comment: If this adjustment makes it to work then that's great

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you've mixed the basic version (non-animated) with the animated one.

For the basic version remove the min-height:0; and replace it with display:none.
This is because your max-height is 0 and your javascript code is changing the display value from 'none' to 'block' and vice-versa on click. Therefore, the element becomes a block element, however, it's height is limited by max-height:0.

Your CSS should be:

```
 .accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or you could just change your JS to change the max-height value instead of the display value.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS replace

```
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

with

```
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've just tested your code and just that replacement get it working

Comment: yes it is working on simulators but not in the template

Comment: Then it could be that there is a wordpress class which is also named as panel. Try your panel class to say nikpanel on both your CSS and html codes

Comment: If still doesn't work then try changing also the accordion and active classes on both your CSS and html to say nikaccordion and nikactive respectively

Comment: And on your javascript i.e accordion to nikaccordion and active to nikactive

Comment: still doesn't work. i've updated the post with this changes under the "upd 1" line

Comment: My last attempt. With these changes I've added the document.ready lines to the javascript and it didn't work. So I'm just wondering whether you still have the document.ready lines(i.e 1st line and last line) on your wordpress code

Comment: i've added "document.ready" line. now this js code adds "nikactive" class to the buttons. but the display property is still unchanged. and this error appears in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Comment: the element "this.nextElementSibling" for some reason returns null on my site and [object HTMLDivElement] on the simulator

Comment: just found out that wordpress console adds p-tags to my code. it puts them where they cannot be like there is no space at the source code but after rendering p-tags appears

Comment: Good morning. I was implying that it won't work if the document.ready lines are on your wordpress javascript. On the W3schools code you will see it doesn't contains those two lines